# Angular ng-repeat and filter error (version 1.1.5 works, 1.2.15 with error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've created a plunker to show the error:

http://plnkr.co/edit/C64fRUQycG2aplmMFZks?p=preview

There's a strange behavior using angular version 1.2.15.

After an operation of drag-n-drop (using jquery.orderable), the filter doesn't work as expected.

How test it:
  There's two versions of angular (1.1.5 and 1.2.15). The error only occurs at 1.2.15.

How to reproduce:
  1. Insert LL as search text (will show just two rows)
  2. Delete the search text content and drag-n-drop the first row (Intant Earthquake and drop at 2nd row).
  3. Use the same text to search ('LL'). Will show just one row.
  4. Delete the search text content, will show just three rows.
  5. Write something to clean the list (asdasdasd) and delete everything.
  6. Will show the whole list

Comment: Angular rule: don't do DOM manipulation in your controller. $('.ul-list') counts as DOM manipulation, move it to a directive. I updated your plnkr to show that angular is still filtering your list correctly here: http://plnkr.co/edit/EYSLy49uV8k9fatQ9IkX?p=preview but the jQuery DOM manipulation is stepping on the toes of angular DOM bindings.

Comment: Thanks! I've removed jQuery and changed to angular ui.sortable directive, and it worked.

Comment: No problem, I posted my comment as an answer so you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular rule: don't do DOM manipulation in your controller. $('.ul-list') counts as DOM manipulation, move it to a directive.

I updated your plnkr to show that angular is still filtering your list correctly here: [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/EYSLy49uV8k9fatQ9IkX?p=preview) but the jQuery DOM manipulation is stepping on the toes of angular DOM bindings.